# Merge 2 separate lists of different types into 1 new list of another type

Tags: c#, list

I'm getting json-data from two separate API:s and then putting them into two lists of separate types. So far all is good, like below:

```
// Instagram
var instaService = new InstagramService();
var instaObj = await instaService.GetInstagramObject("my company", searchOpt.MinMaxId);

// Flickr
var options = new PhotoSearchOptions { PerPage = 20, Page = 1, UserId = "*************" };
PhotoCollection photos = FlickrManager.GetInstance().PhotosSearch(options);
```

But then I need to put them together into another list (of another type), to be showed in GUI ordered by date.

Below is what I've achieved so far. But when 'AddRange' 'var media' is empty. What's wrong here. I want 'var media' to hold values, now they ar null.

```
foreach (var item in instaObj.items)
{
    var media = model.ImportedMedia.Select(o => new MediaImport
    {
        Id = item.id,
        MediaUrl = item.images.standard_resolution.url,
        CreatedTime = item.created_time
    }).ToList();

    model.ImportedMedia.AddRange(media);

}

foreach (var item in photos)
{
    var media = model.ImportedMedia.Select(o => new MediaImport
    {
        Id = item.PhotoId,
        MediaUrl = item.Medium640Url,
        CreatedTime = item.DateUploaded.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    }).ToList();

    model.ImportedMedia.AddRange(media);
}
```

Comment: there is something strange with your logic
are you sure you need that code like `model.ImportedMedia.Select....`, looks like you need only  `var media = new MediaImport() { Id = item.Id, ..};`  and `model.importMedia.Add(media)`;

Comment: On each iteration of your for loop you're fetching ImportedMedia and then "transforming" it into a list containing nothing but `ImportedMedia.Length` items with just the data of the current item you're processing. I think you're doing something really wrong there. You're not even using the `o` variable from your `Select`.

Comment: If (as I assume) "model.ImportedMedia" is empty initially (at the start of the method), then the "Select" on it will not select anything.
Because you are already iterating over "instaObj.items", one tihng you can do in your existing code is just create a new MediaImport object and add it to "model.ImportedMedia"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are creating the `media` variables from `model.ImportedMedia` itself, then adding it. If `model.ImportedMedia` is initially empty, then no elements will be added.

I think what you want is:

```
var media1 = instaObj.items.Select(item => new MediaImport
{
    Id = item.id,
    MediaUrl = item.images.standard_resolution.url,
    CreatedTime = item.created_time
});

var media2 = photos.Select(item => new MediaImport
{
    Id = item.PhotoId,
    MediaUrl = item.Medium640Url,
    CreatedTime = item.DateUploaded.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
});

model.ImportedMedia.AddRange(media1);
model.ImportedMedia.AddRange(media2);
```

Answer (score 4):

Why are you calling `Select` on `model.ImportedMedia`? I think what you want to do is this:

```
model.ImportedMedia.AddRange(instaObj.items.Select(item =>
    new MediaImport {
        Id = item.id,
        MediaUrl = item.images.standard_resolution.url,
        CreatedTime = item.created_time
    });
```

followed by

```
model.ImportedMedia.AddRange(photos.Select(photo => new MediaImport
    {    
        Id = photo.PhotoId,
        MediaUrl = photo.Medium640Url,
        CreatedTime = photo.DateUploaded.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to operate on your collections that you are iterating instead like this

```
var media1 = instaObj.items.Select(o => new MediaImport
{
    Id = o.id,
    MediaUrl = o.images.standard_resolution.url,
    CreatedTime = o.created_time
});

var media2 = photos.Select(o => new MediaImport
{
    Id = o.PhotoId,
    MediaUrl = o.Medium640Url,
    CreatedTime = o.DateUploaded.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
});

var mergedList = media1.Union(media2).ToList();
```

Currently it feels a bit like you are mixing apples and pears.